# iOS shared UIMenuController probably cache UIMenuItem

Tags: ios, caching, ios6, uimenucontroller

I think the following image can describe the problem pretty well...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd1syth3gce6qh7/ios_uimenucontroller.png

I also copy corresponding code part here:

```
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self];
selectedLine = [self lineAtPoint:point];

if(selectedLine) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    UIMenuController *menuController = [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] retain];
    NSLog(@"count: %d", [[menuController menuItems] count]);
    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"???" action:@selector(delete:)];
    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: menuItem, nil]];
    NSLog(@"count: %d", [[menuController menuItems] count]);

    for (UIMenuItem *item in [menuController menuItems]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [item title]);
    }

    [menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 2, 2) inView:self];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    [menuController release];
    [menuItem release];
} else {
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
}

[linesInProcess removeAllObjects];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

---

**Console output:**
2012-10-15 14:02:16.450 TouchTracker[8808:c07] Tap
2012-10-15 14:02:16.455 TouchTracker[8808:c07] count: 0
2012-10-15 14:02:16.455 TouchTracker[8808:c07] count: 1
2012-10-15 14:02:16.456 TouchTracker[8808:c07] ???
2012-10-15 14:02:16.459 TouchTracker[8808:c07] line released

---

Only one UIMenuItem is added to UIMenuController, and only one in the menuItems NSArray during runtime, but two menu items are appear in the simulator.

If I click on Delete item, it'll send *delete:* message to self. Actually the title was "Delete" previously, and it looks like it's cached somehow.

Already tried to *Reset Content and Settings* on iPhone Simulator. Also deleted the content of the DerivedData folder... no solution yet. Will also test on a device soon.

Do you have any idea?

Here you can find the complete project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg9ol63aa05px26/TouchTracker.zip

Thanks in advance,
 Gabor Orosz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Delete" is a system menu item that is always visible. Your custom menu items are added to that. 
From the [UIMenuController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html):

> The Delete menu item was added to the set of system menu items.
>   Tapping it invokes the UIResponderStandardEditActions action method
>   delete:, also added in iOS 3.2.

Comment: Thank you for the tip... actually the solution was to change this: 
-(void)delete:(UIMenuItem *)sender 
to:
-(void)deleteLine:(UIMenuItem *)sender

It looks like delete name is used by the system! Ouch! :)